# Electric current in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electric-current

Quick question:

I want to find an expression for the (electric) current density of an electron, in quantum mechanics. Either a single electron or a general charge distribution $\rho$.

Classically   **j**=$\rho $ **v**.

What should I use here?

Maybe the electric charge multiplied by the probability current?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, $\vec \jmath(x,y,z)$ should be defined as $e$ times the Schrodinger probability current. 
\begin{equation*} \vec \jmath = \frac{e\hbar}{2mi}\left(\Psi^* \frac{\partial \Psi }{\partial x}- \left(\frac{\partial \Psi^* }{\partial x}\right)\Psi \right) , \quad e\lt 0. \end{equation*}
That's possible to explicitly see in the formalism of quantum field theory. The definition $\vec v(x,y,z)/\rho $ would be no good because "the velocity of the electron at a particular point $(x,y,z)$" isn't too well-defined due to the uncertainty principle (if the position is given, the velocity is not).

One may be puzzled because the expression for $\vec\jmath$ above isn't an operator – it is quadratic in the wave function. But in quantum field theory, it *is* an operator – an observable – because it is a function of the field operators $\Psi$.

If we consider non-relativistic quantum mechanics with fixed coordinates of particles and we still want to define $\vec\jmath(x,y,z)$ as a linear operator, an observable, we must appreciate that this operator is only nonzero is the particle is located in the infinitesimal vicinity of the point $(x,y,z)$. So we have
$$\rho (x_0,y_0,z_0) = e \delta^{(3)}(\hat{\vec r}-\vec r_0) $$
and
$$\vec\jmath (x_0,y_0,z_0) = \frac e2\{\delta^{(3)}(\hat{\vec r}-\vec r_0),\frac{\hat{\vec p}}{m} \}$$
I had to write one-half of the commutator with the velocity operator because functions of positions and velocities don't commute but we still need a Hermitian operator.

If there are $N$ charged particles, the operators $\hat{\vec r}$ and $\hat{\vec p}$ acquire an extra index from $1$ to $N$ and $\rho(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ and $\vec\jmath(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ must be written as a sum of the expressions over this index.

One may verify that e.g. for wave packets, the integrals over $\vec r_0$ (some regions) give us what we would expect.

Comment: By “fixed coordinates of particles” do you mean point charges? A point charge would have an infinite spread in momentum, so how would current even be meaningful?

Comment: Dear HelloBye, first, I always consider point charges in this answer and physics before string theory always does. It just means that the internal structure of the elementary particles is non-existent. But it doesn't mean that the position of the particle is sharp. These are different quantities - the internal radius of the electron is something else than the uncertainty of its position.

Comment: Second, indeed, we can consider the basis of fixed coordinates of point charges and indeed, each vector in this position basis has an infinite uncertainty of the momentum. One can still calculate the current for such bases and while somewhat singular, this basis is very convenient for calculations.

Comment: Ok, well it may be convenient, how is it justified physically? Thank you for your response

Comment: Dear Liam, in quantum mechanics, the processes transforming the initial states to the final states are given by a linear unitary operator. This linear operator is fully encoded by its matrix elements relatively to the initial basis and the final basis, as a matrix in any bases one chooses. Whatever basis is chosen, one gets a description that is exactly as physically justified as the description based on any other basis. To calculate specific processes, one must insert the experimentally relevant initial and final state - contract the matrix with these two states to get the amplitude.