# How does the definition of current account for the wave nature of electrons?

Tags: electrons, electric-current, wave-particle-duality

I have a classical (perhaps incorrect?) understanding of current being the number of coulombs (a quantity) of electrons passing through a given point point in a second.

How does the definition current work in the context of electrons being waves?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/95826/electric-current-in-quantum-mechanics

Comment: Electric current is not defined in terms of number of electrons but in terms of charge transferred through circuit. People operated with the notion of electric current way before the quantum physics was developed.  And "electrons are waves" is not quite the real picture.

Comment: What's the difference, when the electrons' charge is the only "charge" in the picture?